# Converting Game of Life images to lists

Tags: image-processing, cellular-automata

I want to convert images of GoL configurations into binary matrices to run in Mathematica's `CellularAutomaton`. I know that there's a collection of GoL patterns in http://conwaylife.com and other sites, but I want to do this from images, as sometimes the same pattern is named differently by different people.

Other than using `Binarize` or `MorphologicalBinarize`, I don't know which image processing functions of Mathematica would be helpful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So far I've got:

```
Manipulate[
 bin = MorphologicalBinarize[imag, {t1, t2}], {t1, 0, 1, 0.1}, {t2, 
  0, 1, 0.1}] (* find the appropriate thresholds for the image *)

MorphologicalComponents @ bin // ArrayPlot
```

and I'm thinking about doing some clustering and deletion of duplicates.

Comment: This is done for the more complicated case of the Wireworld CA [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/137758).

Comment: @C.E. Thanks, that's interesting. The image processing case is quite different though, the image there has no mesh, and even though it has colors it's easier to process spatially. Quote form the link: "It seems like every cell of WireWorld structure corresponds to exactly one pixel in that frame".

Comment: You're right, the Wireworld CA is more complicated, but it's easier to extract the information from that image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First import the image and remove the white edge around it (if there is no edge then omit this step):

```
img = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiZpI.png"];
img = ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[img]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Count the number of cells in each direction:

```
data = ImageData[img];

rows[m_] := Unitize@Total[m]
columns[m_] := rows[Transpose@m]

{nx, ny} = {
   SequenceCount[rows[data], {1 ..}],
   SequenceCount[columns[data], {1 ..}]
   };
```

Create an empty grid:

```
grid = With[{r = rows[data], c = columns[data]}, Image[
   ConstantArray[r, Length[c]] Transpose@ConstantArray[c, Length[r]]
   ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`MorphologicalComponents` can find each cell in this grid:

```
MorphologicalComponents[grid] // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This result can be used as the label matrix for `ComponentMeasurements`, which allows us to get information from the real image while using components that were found using the empty grid:

```
cells = ComponentMeasurements[
   {img, MorphologicalComponents[grid]},
   {"Centroid", "Median"}
   ];
```

The problem now is that we have all the data, but we don't know what the matrix index should be for each cell. We solve that by sorting the cells based on their centroids, first by their y value and then by their x values. I'm giving the y value extra weight to achieve this:

```
rank[_ -> {{x_, y_}, _}] := x + 10^15 y

ArrayPlot[
 Reverse@Partition[SortBy[cells, rank][[All, 2, 2]], nx],
 ColorRules -> {0 -> Black, 1 -> White}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach that uses correlation with the boxes. Each box is 12 by 12 (hence the "divide by 12" in the `PixelValuePositions`). The first two lines remove the extra alpha channel and fake-color data from the image. The output is a list of the box positions.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCY7B.png"];
imgNeg = ColorNegate[ColorConvert[RemoveAlphaChannel[img], "Grayscale"]];
pos = Ceiling[PixelValuePositions[
      ImageConvolve[imgNeg, BoxMatrix[5]]//ImageAdjust, 1.]/12.];
{img, Rotate[SparseArray[pos -> 1] // ArrayPlot, Pi/2]}
```

[image]

```
pos

{{6, 12}, {12, 12}, {5, 11}, {6, 11}, {7, 11}, {11, 11}, {12, 11}, {13, 11}, 
{4, 10}, {7, 10}, {11, 10}, {14, 10}, {3, 9}, {4, 9}, {5, 9}, {13, 9}, {14, 9}, 
{15, 9}, {4, 8}, {6, 8}, {12, 8}, {14, 8}, {6, 7}, {7, 7}, {11, 7}, {12, 7}, {2, 6}, 
{7, 6}, {11, 6}, {16, 6}, {7, 5}, {11, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {7, 4}, {11, 4}, {15, 4},
{16,4}, {4, 3}, {7, 3}, {11, 3}, {14, 3}, {6, 2}, {12, 2}}
```

It's missing the top row and right-hand column because there is nothing there (in the SparseArray).

Comment: Thanks, that's nice! However, take a look at this case: `img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiZpI.png"]; 
imgNeg = ColorNegate[
   ColorConvert[RemoveAlphaChannel[img], "Grayscale"]];
imgData = 
  ImageData[ImageConvolve[imgNeg, BoxMatrix[5]] // ImageAdjust];
SparseArray[Ceiling[Position[imgData, 1.]/12.] -> 1] // ArrayPlot`

Comment: I've tried adjusting the divisor, but it's still off. 

`img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiZpI.png"];
imgNeg = ColorNegate[
   ColorConvert[RemoveAlphaChannel[img], "Grayscale"]];
imgData = 
  ImageData[ImageConvolve[imgNeg, BoxMatrix[5]] // ImageAdjust];
Manipulate[
 positions = 
  Ceiling[PixelValuePositions[
     ImageConvolve[imgNeg, BoxMatrix[5]] // ImageAdjust, 1.]/divisor];
 Row[{img, ArrayPlot[SparseArray[positions -> 1], Mesh -> True]}]
 , {divisor, 1., 12., 1.}]`

Answer (score 5):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCY7B.png"];

{dim1, dim2} = ImageDimensions@img/30 // Round
```

> {7, 5}

```
r = Length @ ImageCorners @ ImageTake[img, {1, dim1}] - 1
c = Length @ ImageCorners @ ImageTake[img, All, {1, dim2}] - 1
```

> 17
>
> 13

```
p = ImagePartition[img, Scaled[{1/r, 1/c}]];
m = Map[DominantColors[#, 1, "LABColor"][[1]] &, p, {-1}]
```

[image]

```
Position[Table[
  m[[i, j]] == LABColor[0, 0, 0], {i, 1, c}, {j, 1, r}],
    True]
```

> {{2, 6}, {2, 12}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 7}, {3, 11}, {3, 12}, {3, 
>     13}, {4, 4}, {4, 7}, {4, 11}, {4, 14}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {5, 
>     13}, {5, 14}, {5, 15}, {6, 4}, {6, 6}, {6, 12}, {6, 14}, {7, 6}, {7,
>      7}, {7, 11}, {7, 12}, {8, 2}, {8, 7}, {8, 11}, {8, 16}, {9, 7}, {9,
>      11}, {10, 2}, {10, 3}, {10, 7}, {10, 11}, {10, 15}, {10, 16}, {11, 
>     4}, {11, 7}, {11, 11}, {11, 14}, {12, 6}, {12, 12}}

---

NOTE: Because `m[[2, 6]] == LABColor[0, 0, 0]` yields `True`, I thought that `Position[m, LABColor[0, 0, 0]]` will work; unfortunately it returns `{}`.

Comment: @core979: thanks, any idea why it fails with `img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiZpI.png"]`?

Comment: I guess it's due to the quality of the images - run `ImageHistogram @ img` on both to see. Doing `img = ImageCrop@Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiZpI.png"]` helps a bit (setting manually `{r, c} = {29, 18}` is easier in this case), but right now I don't know how to ovecome the imperfect `LABColor`s...